# Javascript code that functioned as * (or LIKE Operator in MYSQL) in onclick function

Tags: javascript, treetable

Is there any code in Javascript that similar as * or LIKE Operator in MYSQL for the following purpose.

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('row1*');"
```

I'm trying to create treetable with dynamic data from database.

In this case, I need to toggle any rows with class=row11, class=row12, class=row13 and class=row14 simultaneously by clicking a row with class=row1.

Then, when I click any row from row11, again it simultaneously toggle rows with class=row111, row112, row113, etc. So for this level, it seems like:

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('row11*');"
```

Need your help please.
Thank you.

Comment: ideally you could just do it with a class.

Comment: There's [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). In this case, the selector would look like `[class^=row1]` or `[class^=row11]`. Of course, this is complicated by the fact you could have more than one class, which might work with `[class*=row1]` for example, unless you have something like `class='row11 striped-row1'`, where you would match the latter as well, possibly where you don't want to.

Comment: @Jared, will it work if the tree is dinamic depend on data? Now its only until class=row14, in the future there will be class=row15 as more data added. It is also happen for the next levels, where there will be more data to be added, class=row114, class=row115, etc.

Comment: If you're querying the DOM (using `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`, you're going to elements in the DOM at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You could either set a common class to the elements and use getElementsByClassName, or you can use querySelector and a starts with selector.

Starts with selector

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="row1"]')
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.add("selected");  
}
```

```css
.selected { color: #00CC00; }
```

```html
<div id="row11">11</div>
<div id="row12">12</div>
<div id="row13">13</div>
<div id="row21">21</div>
<div id="row22">22</div>
<div id="row23">23</div>
```

Comment: He's using classes already. I'm guessing that's because there might be more than one tree on the page.